# How to get rid of non-existing module visible in modules list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-module

I'm working with brew python 3.7 distribution on macOS High Sierra. When installing several modules at once via `pip install [modules...]` I came across several errors that I dealt with at the time. 
However now when accessing to modules list via `pip list` at the beginning of the list the following information is displayed:

```
Package                           Version    
--------------------------------- -----------
-                                 r          
-BB                               0.1        
-br                               5.4.1      
-ock                              2.0.0      
-ocutils                          0.15.1     
-r                                5.4.1      
-stropy                           3.2.1      
absl-py                           0.7.1
... remaining normal modules ...
```

Those 'modules' seem to be parts of names of actually existing modules. With general uninstall procedure like: `pip uninstall -BB` or
`pip uninstall '-BB'` I cannot remove none of those 'modules'. How to get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like those packages are dependency of other packages you have installed
you can check the dependency tree with [pipdeptree](https://github.com/naiquevin/pipdeptree) 
lookout for those packages you mentioned see if they're dependency of other packages